# Getting [Directory not found] error while reading .xml file from airflow dag

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have written few dags in airflow using SimpleHttpOperator. I want to send a message in form of xml in case of any failure. As the message remains same for all the dags, I have seperated it out and kept inside an xml file. In my local machine, the xml is present in the root folder(D:\airflow-dags\test.xml) and the dags are inside (D:\airflow-dags\dags\dag.py). I am using the following snippet to read the xml.

```
f = open("../../test.xml", "r")
    message = f.read()
```

It is working well in my local machine, but when I deploy it to airflow, it shows directory not found error. Is there any way so that I can fetch the file from airflow as well. Do I need to add that file explicitly in airflow?

Comment: consider using path building utilities from `os.path` to make sure your path is portable and correct no matter where you use it. Hardcoding `../` in paths may cause problems like these

Comment: Sure, I will do that, but how can I add that file in airflow, this file is in my local machine. I need to add in airflow so that the dags can access it.